# preview text in textview Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been using the following when creating layouts using the preview tool in Android Studio.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
    android:text="87%" />
```

The drawback is, if there is a delay before the real value is available, the UI will show `87%` for a split second.

What are my options to handle this nicely?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For preview-only purposes, use the `tools` namespace:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
    tools:text="87%" />
```

This way the text only shows in IDE but not in runtime environment.

Declare `tools` with `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in your XML's root element.